# Django path error while trying install skin for Admin

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install the [following](https://github.com/sainipray/djadmin) skin for my Django admin. I followed all the instructions till the part where I have to update my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

`url(r'^admin/', include('djadmin.urls')),`

I've changed the code and tried entering

`path('admin/', djadmin.urls),`

also tried
`path('admin/', include(djadmin.urls)),`

But its still giving me an error in this line of code. I've added djadmin to my installed files and also updated the middleware.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: can add the error traceback?

Comment: File "D:\Pycharm work\Buggie\Buggie\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('admin/', include(djadmin.urls)),
NameError: name 'djadmin' is not defined

Comment: Add it to the question.

Comment: @Kaushal Sharma I added one answer. Please do try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **quote symbols** (***" and "***) to the `djadmin.urls` as

```
path('admin/', include("djadmin.urls")),
```